# os.walk returns differently encoded non-ascii (unicode) filenames, how to deal with it?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode

Exactly the same code, ran on Mac OsX and CentOS 7 return different results:

```
>>> path = u'examples'
>>> import os
>>> walker = os.walk(path, followlinks=True)
>>> list(walker)
```

On CentOS:

```
[u'filename-with-un\xec\u010d\xf8\u0111e-chars.txt', ... ]
```

On MacOSX:

```
[u'filename-with-uni\u0300c\u030c\xf8\u0111e-chars.txt', ... ]
```

BTW, The actual file name is `filename-with-unìčøđe-chars.txt`

What causes this behaviour, and how can we avoid it?

Comment: Have you looked at this method:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize

Comment: @JeremyJStarcher NO! I HAVENT! UNTIL NOW! AND NOW THE THING WORKS! AND I'M GOING TO TURN OFF MY CAPSLOCK SOMETIME TOMORROW, PROBABLY! THANK YOU!!!111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour is caused by different unicode normalization forms for filenames on OS X and Cent OS.

The [Technical Report #15](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/) of unicode.org defines the available forms, but Apple uses a slight variant for HFS+ as documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1173/_index.html).

So in one case you have NFD on OS X/HFS+, and in the other you have NFC for Linux (if you are in the happy case that your filesystem encoding is defined at all for Linux, which isn't always the case, see [Wheeler](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/fixing-unix-linux-filenames.html) for a lot of the issues you might find).

So, fundamentally you cannot avoid the behaviour, its the native filesystem that does that.

But if you ask differently, you might get a more satisfying answer. You can compare the names in meaningful ways, either by normalizing to a common normalization form etc., depends on why you need to compare them. Python offers normalization functions in the `unicodedata` module, with the `normalize()` function.